# Django pass user to ModelForm to use in ModelChoiceField query

Tags: python, django, django-queryset, modelform

So, I have a ModelForm for a post. The form includes a ModelChoiceField that displays the courses a user can post to. I only want a user to post to the courses that they are subscribed to. Right now, every single course to included in the course queryset.

Basically, I want to pass `request.user` to my PostForm and use that for the course ModelChoiceField queryset. I'm with this code right now; the logic makes sense to me but it does not work :/

```
class PostForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Post
        fields = ('course', 'content', 'image')

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        user = kwargs.pop("user", None)
        if user is not None:
            self.course.queryset = user.profile.courses.all()
        super(PostForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

   course = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=Course.objects.all())
   content = forms.CharField(widget=forms.Textarea(attrs={'rows': 5, 'cols': 50}))
```

The error I get is `AttributeError at /'PostForm' object has no attribute 'course'`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The correct syntax is something like:

```
self.fields['course'].queryset = Course.objects.filter([...])
```

I recommend you use the excellent [django braces](http://django-braces.readthedocs.org/).

[`UserKwargModelFormMixin`](http://django-braces.readthedocs.org/en/latest/form.html#userkwargmodelformmixin) is what you are looking for.

Comment: Hey that worked! I didn't realize that was right in the docs. Thanks man.